# Is possible to run a query with linq to search for a period of time?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2005

Problem details:

- SQL Server 2005;
- Entity Framework 4.0.

I'm trying with linq to run a query for a period of time, only. Exemple:

I have the following `datetime` data in my server:

```
30/03/2012 12:53:22
30/03/2012 17:23:29
04/04/2012 11:10:14
04/04/2012 19:06:55
```

I want to run a query that will return me all data between the time (12:00 and 20:00) and the query have to return to me the following data:

```
30/03/2012 12:53:22
30/03/2012 17:23:29
04/04/2012 19:06:55
```

Or between (11:00 and 13:00) and the query have to return to me the following data:

```
30/03/2012 12:53:22
04/04/2012 11:10:14
```

How can i do this with linq? Is it possible (to ignore the date, use only the time)?

Answer (score 3):

```
var filteredTimes = myContext.MyTable
   .Where(r => SqlFunctions.DatePart("hour", r.DateField) >= 11 &&
               SqlFunctions.DatePart("hour", r.DateField) <= 13);
```

You need to include `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` to get `SqlFunctions`.

Comment: If i want to compare all the time (hour, minute and second), i put only second, or there is a "TotalSeconds"?

Comment: "The version of SQL Server in use does not support datatype 'time'."

Comment: It translates to the Sql [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420(v=sql.90).aspx) function so you can use any options that provides you. There's no total seconds, but you can do each part individually. As for the second problem, that sounds like something wrong with your edmx, not necessarily the call to SqlFunctions.DatePart

Answer (score 0):

If you convert the date value to a double and use the fractional part of if, you get a number between 0 and 1 that represents a time in a day. Having that, it is trivial to test for time intervals, where e.g. 13:45 would be 0,5729166667 (or more precise: 13:45.345 is 0,572920679).

You can do this because EF (i.e. 4.3, the version I use) translates Cast and even Math functions into SQL:

```
mycontext.Data.Where(dt => dt.DateTime.HasValue)
    .Select(dt => dt.DateTime.Value).Cast<double>()
    .Select(d => d -  Math.Floor(d))
    .Where(... your comparisons
```

This translates to Sql containing `CAST([date column] AS float)` and Sql's `FLOOR` function.

---

After your comments:

It looked so easy, but I can't find a way to instruct EF to do a `CAST` on a single property in a `Select()`. Only the `Cast<>()` function is translated to `CAST` (sql), but that operates on a set.

Well, fortunately, there is another way:

```
mycontext.Data.Where(dt => dt.DateTime.HasValue)
.Select(dt => new
    {
      Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dt.DateTime.Value),
      Ms = DbFunctions.DiffMilliseconds(
               DbFunctions.TruncateTime(dt.DateTime.Value), dt.DateTime.Value)
    })
.Where(x => x.Ms > lower && x.Ms < upper)
```

where `lower` and `upper` are the `TotalMilliseconds` property of `TimeSpan` objects.

Note that this is horribly inefficient in sql! The date functions are repeated for each comparison. So make sure that you do the comparisons on a set of data that has been confined as much as possible by other criteria. It may even be better to fetch data in memory first and then do the comparisons.

Note: prior to EF6, `DbFunctions` was `EntityFunctions`.

Comment: Ok, with this i convert the datetime that i have in mycontext, and how do i convert the datetime that i have as parameter to double, to do my comparison?

Comment: Something like `new TimeSpan(0,13,45,0,0).TotalMilliseconds / new TimeSpan(0,24,0,0,0).TotalMilliseconds` for 13:45.

Comment: With this, 'll be returned a IQueryble<double>, but, if i want to do this comparison and return IQueryble<Data>, is it possible? (to keep doing another comparisons based in anothers parameters... in this case, if these comparions are required in another part of the code)

Answer (score -1):

-You can use the TimeOfDay property on the dates to compare them.

```
string timeAsString = "13:00";

from f in TableRows
where f.Date.TimeOfDay > DateTime.Parse("11-12-2012 "+timeAsString).TimeOfDay
select f
```

---

## EDIT

here is some code you can test that runs for me:

```
  DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("12-12-2012 13:00");
  List<DateTime> dates = new List<DateTime>();
  dates.Add(DateTime.Parse("12-12-2012 13:54"));
  dates.Add(DateTime.Parse("12-12-2012 12:55"));
  dates.Add(DateTime.Parse("12-12-2012 11:34"));
  dates.Add(DateTime.Parse("12-12-2012 14:53"));

  var result = (from f in dates where f.TimeOfDay > d.TimeOfDay select f);
```

---

## EDIT 2

Yea it seems that you needed to .ToList(), which, tbh you should have been able to figure out. I had no way of knowing what of collection you had. Not sure either of us deserve a downvote for trying to help you when you don't supply an awful amount of information on the problem

Comment: Is not possible to use DateTime.Parse inside a Linq query. =(

Comment: Why i have to put a date? I don't want to use the date, my doubt is that, if is possible to do this comparison without using the date in SQL Server 2005 (with the EF layer).

Comment: "The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities." - Are you testing it before post? =/

Comment: Because you are using Linq to Object not Linq to Entities.

Answer (score -1):

If you had a `date` and a `time` column in your table (as possible with SQL Server 2008), you could do this directly in SQL.

As that's not the case, you have to do it like this:

```
// the first two lines can be omitted, if your bounds are already timespans
var start = startDate.TimeOfDay;
var end = endDate.TimeOfDay;
var filteredItems = context.Items.ToList()
    .Where(x => x.DateTimeColumn.TimeOfDay >= start
        && x.DateTimeColumn.TimeOfDay <= end);
```

Comment: Like i said, i have a `datetime data`, not a `date` and `time`. Doesn't exist in SQL Server 2005 the `time` type, only in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: You could just try the mentioned _alternate approach_ then (which _doesn't_ require you to use a `time` column for the cost of being slower).

Comment: "The specified type member 'TimeOfDay' is not supported in LINQ to Entities." - Are you testing it before post? =/

Comment: You have to use `ToList()` (which I used in my example above) or `AsEnumerable` on your object query before filtering to get LINQ to do the evaluation on the client side.

Comment: And if i have a 2kk of data, i have to return all and after run the "split"?

Comment: Either that or write the query yourself (with all the mapping that follows). But if you really have that much data, a manual query/stored procedure will be much faster.